# loading aspx page in classic asp in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp-classic

i am trying to load a aspx in a classic asp using this code:

```
 <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252" %>

 <html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#menu').load('Menuin.aspx', function () {
    alert('menu inserted');
});
</script>
  <body>
  <div id="menu"></div>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

Can u let me know the mistake i'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include JQuery.

You also have to wait for the DOM to load.

wrap it with

```
$(function() {
 // your code here.
});
```

Comment: no man.. I did this let me know if anything is wrong  :$(function(){
    $('#menu').load('Menuin.aspx'){
        alert('menu inserted')   }  ;
    });

Comment: @user - he means you need to actually *reference* jQuery in a script tag - i.e. `<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>` ... you'll also need to do that **before** your script tag where you *use* jQuery.